# XQuery syntax to declare a namespace: [XPST0081] No namespace declared for 'text:p'

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, exist-db, basex

What is the syntax to declare a namespace for [Libre Office](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60221464/262852), and what specific namespace needs to be declared?

```
thufir@dur:~/fods/flwor$ 
thufir@dur:~/fods/flwor$ basex text.xq 
Stopped at /home/thufir/fods/flwor/text.xq, 3/14:
[XPST0081] No namespace declared for 'text:p'.
thufir@dur:~/fods/flwor$ 
thufir@dur:~/fods/flwor$ cat text.xq 

for $foo  in db:open("foo")
return $foo//text:p

thufir@dur:~/fods/flwor$
```

Of course, returning `$foo` by itself works fine to return the document in its entirety.

Do I need the namespace stored locally in a file, also?  Or, just [add](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48443516/262852) something *like*:

`declare namespace type4="http:///de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/api/segmentation/type.ecore";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every namespace prefix you use **in your query** must be declared in the query, too. In your case you can add a line

```
declare namespace text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0";
```

at the top to fix your query.

Since the namespace prefixes (`text` in your case) are only a reference to the associated namespace URI, it does not have to match the prefix in the XML document. The following query is 100% equivalent:

```
declare namespace whatever="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0";

for $foo in db:open("foo")
return $foo//whatever:p
```